# Real Time PCR Test Chemistry

Tags: pcr, diy-biology

I am working on building a real time PCR machine. Is there any chemistry set that I can purchase online to:

1. Identify if PCR amplification was successfully done.
2. Test fluorescence dyes that could be used to validate if the fluorescence detector optics worked; i.e. something I could excite with a specific wavelength and monitor for fluorescence.

I am looking for something that is not dangerous and only serves the single purpose of validating the real time PCR machine.

*Mods please advise if I need to move to Chemistry StackExchange*

Comment: Are you asking for specific and proven techniques ? or information on something like a thermocycler? Other than that, I have no idea what a pcr "machine" is.

Comment: I am asking for two things 1) Something that will confirm that PCR occurred (ie color change after 30 cycles of PCR). 2) Something that will fluoresce at a specific frequency when excited by an excitation frequency.

Comment: What level of accuracy do you expect for the identification of the PCR product?

Comment: If you're looking for a simple fluorophore just to make sure your detector is working, [Auto parts stores](http://www.autozone.com/test-scan-and-specialty-tools/uv-light-and-accessories/quest-25-oz-universal-uv-dye-bulk/210223_0_0/?checkfit=true) carry fluorescent dyes to track oil leaks. Probably won't be useful for measuring amount of DNA though.

Comment: I just remembered that I used to extract fluorescent dyes from highlighters by breaking them open and passing ethanol through the marker. That would be another easy source of dyes to test your detector.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different ways to detect PCR product in real-time PCR: dyes which bind to DNA in general, such as [SYBR Green I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYBR_Green_I), or probes specific to your PCR product. There's a summary of the benefits of each [here](https://www.thermofisher.com/uk/en/home/life-science/pcr/real-time-pcr/qpcr-education/taqman-assays-vs-sybr-green-dye-for-qpcr.html#compare), with the following table:

[image: table comparing SYBR and Taqman real-time chemistries]

You can buy either online; they'll be fairly expensive but I can't think of an obvious way to get them cheaper if you're interested in high-confidence validation.

[edit] forgot to mention that you will also need to normalise the reporter signal against a reference dye such as ROX (https://www.thermofisher.com/order/catalog/product/12223012).